# Need regex for parts of string in url

Tags: javascript, regex, url

What I have is this string..

```
/website.com/index.php/Tools/Misc/renderer
```

What I need to get from this is

```
/website.com/index.php/Tools/Misc/
```

I can use jQuery and/or plain javascript to get this string.

Comment: If you want a Regex you'll need to be a bit more descriptive. Is this always the case (removing the last piece of the URI)? How do you handle query/search strings? What about when there aren't pieces to the path - what do you expect?

Comment: It will always be in this form, fortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do this, without regex

```
var str = "/website.com/index.php/Tools/Misc/renderer";
var newStr = str.substr(0,str.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
console.log(newStr); // "/website.com/index.php/Tools/Misc/"
```

Remove +1 in second line if you don't want a trailing slash.

Comment: Is this a preferred method over using regex or the below split and join methods?

Comment: @Angelo I would say yes, since regex is a bit overkill and creating array and joining for a simple work is too a overkill.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the below regex to remove  all the characters which are just after to the last `/` symbol.

```
> "/website.com/index.php/Tools/Misc/renderer".replace(/[^\/]*$/g, '')
'/website.com/index.php/Tools/Misc/'
```

Answer (score 1):

This removes the last part of your path

```
var st = '/website.com/index.php/Tools/Misc/renderer'.split(/\/[^/]+$/).join('/');
```